# Convert ER-Diagram to SQL

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I have trouble with converting an ER-Diagram into valid SQL code.

Look at the following ER-Diagram

[image]

How can I translate this ER-Diagram into SQL code? I Have trouble specifying  the relations. Would it make sense to create a third table just for the relations?

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
    Fac.-Nr INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (  Fac.-Nr)
);

CREATE TABLE Prof (
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Name)
);
```

I think that I have to work with constraints but I don't know how to properly convert the relations.

I want to be able to insert the following information:

|Name     |belongs to        | leads|

|Smith |   Fac10        |      -|

|Becker |  Fac10        |      Fac10|

|John   |  Fac10          |    -|

I'm very new to SQL so please be patient with me :)

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, have I understood correctly: each prof can only belong to one faculty. There can be many different profs in one faculty, but only one of them can be its head?

Comment: That`s right. What I don't understand is how to convert that to sql

Comment: @cars10 I edited the question a little bit.

Comment: @ViktorG Not tied specifically to what you're asking.  but I would highly advise against naming a column as "Fac.-Ng".  Having a dot in the name can easily lead you down a flurry of problems later on down the road.  Most databases follow a convention of using snake case.  So "fac_ng".

Comment: @dvsoukup you are right! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should create a third table to hold the relation which will point to both table primary key as `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. Something like

```
create table ProfFaculti (
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Nr INTEGER NOT NULL,
primary key(name,Nr),
foreign key(name) references Prof(name), 
foreign key(Nr) references Faculti(Nr))
```

You should actually have some `ID` column in both table which should be the primary key and should have FK on those columns.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does that work with my edited question ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know about "converting" an ER-diagram into SQL, but the current relationship can be modelled by simply having two tables:

```
create table profs ( pid int primary key, pname nvarchar(128), facid int );

create table facs ( fid int primary key, fname nvarchar(128), fpid int );
```

Apart from `pname` you can of course add all the attributes that describe a professor and the same applies for the faculty attributes in table `facs`. But the two columns `facid` in `profs` and `fpid` in `facs` describe adequately the relationships you laid out in your question.

As long, as one prof can belong to only one faculty at a time and the faculty can only have one head, you don't need another link-table connecting the two.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you explain how that is correct? isn't it necessary to connect the tables via foreign-keys?

Comment: This is probably not the "school way" if doing things, but in practice it is quite enough to link the tables in an appropriate manor. Foreign key restrictions are useful, when you are dealing with link tables as they are helpful in keeping things in a sanitized state.